# Getting the text from UITextField within a UIAlertView to set the text of a label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label that is used to create a timer. I also have 2 buttons that are below it, start, and stop as most commonly used. When I press the start button, I have an alert that appears, and it has a text field within the alert. Everything works fine, but when I click my button within my alert "Start timer" I want the label to have the number i set in my text field as the timer, and count down. Could anyone please help me with that. I have searched google, even tried multiple times using label.text = [textField.text intValue] and all that sort of stuff. Thanks in advance

```
- (NSString*)getTimeStr : (int) time {
seconds = time % 60;
minutes = time / 60;
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
}

- (IBAction)startTimer{
    // having the user enter a number in seconds
UIAlertView *inputAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                       initWithTitle:@"Enter The Time:"
               message:@"Enter your time in seconds\n"
                   delegate:self
                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                   otherButtonTitles:@"Start Timer", nil];

UITextField *inputField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
inputField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[inputAlert addSubview:inputField];
[inputAlert setTag:1];
[inputAlert show];

NSInteger buttonIndex;

if([inputAlert tag] == 1) {
    if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        clicked = TRUE;
        mainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                                     target:self 
                                                   selector:@selector(startTimer) 
                                                   userInfo:nil 
                                                    repeats:YES];
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 0) {
        clicked = FALSE;
        [inputAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
} 

//NSString *intFromTextField = [inputField text];
//int time = [intFromTextField intValue];
timeLabel.text = [self getTimeStr:(int)inputField.text];
[timeLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier New" size:140]];
```

}

Comment: UIAlertViews don't have any controls. Are you manually adding a textField to its hierarchy? If so, this is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so, two big things here:

First up, you should set the [`alertViewStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertView/alertViewStyle) property to [`UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIAlertViewStyle), instead of adding your own textfield to an alertview.

The second thing is that you're not converting your string to an integer properly. Well, you are, but, it's commented out for some reason. You can't just cast it. If you do that, you'll wind up with the memory address of the object, not the value. You'll want to call [`integerValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/integerValue) on the string instead.

So, you'll have something like the following, where you use a [`UIAlertViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAlertViewDelegate) callback and access the textfield through the [`textFieldAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/textFieldAtIndex%3a) method:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex {
    // Your existing timer code. It's pretty okay as it is.

    NSUInteger enteredInteger = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text integerValue];
    myLabel.text = [self getTimeStr:enteredInteger];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't set label.text to intValue, because label.text requires an instance of NSString. SO don't need to add .intValue;

Are you adding UITextField as a subview of UIAlertView? If yes, then try to add it with some tag:

```
[youtTextField setTag:777];
[yourAlertView addSubview:yourTextField] 
// you can access yourTextField as a subview with tag = 777
```

If you use UIAlertView you have to set its delegate:
    [yourAlertView setDelegate:self];
UIAlertView's delegate must conform to UIAlertViewDelegate protocol, so in your viewController's .h file add:

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

In order to conform to that protocol you must implement the following method in your ViewController:

```
// this method is called when user taps one of AlertView's buttons
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex   
{
    // as I told, you have to have yourAlertView and timeLabel as class variables
    NSString *button=[yourAlertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Start Timer"]) 
    {
            NSString * timeValue = ((UITextField*)[yourAlertView viewWithTag:777]).text;
            [timeLabel setText:timeValue] // set text for your label
            [timeLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier New" size:140]];
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to set timeLabel and alertView as class variables:

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    UIAlertView * yourAlertView;
    UILabel * timeLabel;
}
```

// some edits to your startTimer: selector:

```
- (IBAction)startTimer{
// having the user enter a number in seconds
    UIAlertView *inputAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                   initWithTitle:@"Enter The Time:"
           message:@"Enter your time in seconds\n"
               delegate:self
               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
               otherButtonTitles:@"Start Timer", nil];

    UITextField *inputField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    [inputField setTag:1];
    inputField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [inputAlert addSubview:inputField];
    [inputAlert show];
}
```